# Browser-sync on Windows 10

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, gulp, browser-sync

I'm trying to use gulp and browser-sync to setup a dev environment on a Windows 10 machine, but I can't get the server to respond.

Accessing localhost:5000 gives me "ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED" on Chrome. I was able to get around this with 127.0.0.1:5000 but now I'm stuck with a browser loading forever.

Here is my gulpfile:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('./public/index.html');
});

app.listen(5000);
```

And my app.js, which starts the server:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
var nodemon = require('gulp-nodemon');


gulp.task('default', ['browser-sync'], function () {
});

gulp.task('browser-sync', ['nodemon'], function() {
    browserSync.init(null, {
        proxy: "http://localhost:5000",
        files: ["public/**/*.*"],
        browser: "google chrome",
        port: 7000,
    });
});
gulp.task('nodemon', function (cb) {

    var started = false;

    return nodemon({
        script: 'app.js'
    }).on('start', function () {
        // to avoid nodemon being started multiple times
        // thanks @matthisk
        if (!started) {
            cb();
            started = true; 
        } 
    });
});
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "tst",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "^2.18.13",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-nodemon": "^2.2.1",
    "pug": "^2.0.0-rc.4"
  }
}
```

For reference, I'm using the code on this repo: https://gist.github.com/sogko/b53d33d4f3b40d3b4b2e

Is there anyway I can get this to work on Windows 10?

Comment: There are a couple of helpful comments on your linked gist.  Just "chrome", not "google chrome" and another about the infinite load issue.

Comment: @Mark Fixed the browser value. Now it correctly launches chrome, but tries to access localhost, which still does not work. Running nodemon on another terminal does not help either.

Comment: did you solve it @FábioQueluci? i'm trying to run browsersync in laravel and it loads forever on localhost:3000